# WCF binding translation

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soa

1) I have an external customer who will be hitting a web service.  This external webservice will be using SSL and signed with a certificate.  No prob here...  This uses wsHttpBinding.

2) I have an internal service that does all the actual work.  It uses SSL without any client credentials.  In other words, we trust our front box.  This uses basicHttpBinding

Question:
  Using .NET 4's router, can I do this without writing any code?  Will the routing service validate the message credential and then translate the message from a wsHttpBinding to a basicHttpBinding?  If not, how do you best propose to solve this problem?  I know I can just implement the service an manually call the client, but I'm wondering if there is a code-less way of doing this with .NET 4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After trying this thing out in code, I got it working.  Nothing really special here, so if you have any questions, please just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying this thing out in code, I got it working. Nothing really special here, just some configuration.